# Pass click event through levels of ScrollViews and Layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have many ScrollViews with RelativeLayouts inside in one Activity all of them cover the whole screen. I got buttons in some of them but the problem is the top layout is blocking the click events for the other layouts.

I want it so if no button is hit at the first layout it passes the click event to next etc.

You may wonder why i have many layouts that covers the whole screen and that is because i got scrollviews in them to create a 3D paralax effect scrolling background with different layers.

On the top layer also have setOnDragListener if that is important.
Here i will try to show you how my setup is:

HorizontalScrollView1--Layout1--Images/Buttons

HorizontalScrollView2--Layout2--Images/Buttons

HorizontalScrollView3--Layout3--Images/Buttons

So right now ScrollView3 is taking all clicks because its in the front/top. I can't disable clicks on the Scroll cut it needs to be scrollable and there is also buttons at the top layer that needs to be clickable.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#intercept

Answer (score 0):

overriding this in the relativelayout and returning true makes the above routine redundant:

```
RelativeLayout slideLayout=new RelativeLayout(mContext){
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mIsMuteTouches) return true;
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
};
```

Comment: onInterceptTouchEvent makes the ScrollView unscrollable =(

Comment: wouldn't `return false` after the if statement be better ? If I understand well the documentation the event would be transfered to the child in case of `return false`